# Type mismatch: Imports in vbs

Tags: vbscript

I am analyzing a vbs script and I cannot debug because of the very first line, say I try running:

```
    Imports System.Class
    Class.WriteLine("hello")
```

Which returns the error "Type mismatch: Imports". I'm working on the cmd.exe because of limitations.

So, what could be the source of this problem?

Is there a way to run this code without having to install something else?

Comment: What do you mean by "I'm working on the cmd.exe"?

Comment: VBScript doesn't support importing external files ([workarounds](http://www.planetcobalt.net/sdb/importvbs.shtml) notwithstanding). What language is this? How are you running this? And what is the *exact* error message?

Comment: Yet another first-time user throwing dirt over the wall and disappearing. :-(

Answer (score 1):

**This surely is not Vbscript code.**

There is no `Imports` statement in Vbscript.

You might be able to create a `WriteLine` method in a `Class` class, and the superfluous brackets would be ignored, but it´s the `Imports` that indicates this is not Vbscript.

(The brackets are superfluous because no matter if `WriteLine` were a `Function` or a `Sub` -- the reference does not use the function result (if it was a function), and thus the brackets would be interpreted as part of the expression that delivers the actual parameter for the first (and only) formal parameter of `WriteLine` because calling a `Sub` or `Function` (without using its return value) does not allow brackets for the argument list.)