# How do I use VBScript to rename files in a directory prepending the folder name to all files in the folder?

Tags: vbscript

I have a large number of image files spanning nearly two decades where the subject is identified by the directory name and most of the photos themselves have a generic name however some of them have more specific names. 
I am writing a script to prepend the directory name to the filename for all files in a specific directory. Well, I am trying to at least.
It has been a few years since I used VBScript and it seems I am VERY rusty.
I am facing challenges with the syntax format.

When I have Option Explicit (on line 6) it gives an error of Line 6, Char 1, Error: Expected Statement, Code: 800A0400 (In my shared code it would be line 7 because of the added Beginning of File line)

If I comment that out, I get an error on the import statements instead of Line 3, char 1, Error: Type mismatch: 'Imports', Code: 800A000D (In my shared code, it would be line 4 because of the added Beginning of File line)

I have spent a few hours googling for possible causes but to no avail and so I am turning to the community for help with getting the formatting of this script set correctly.

Any comments on a better script approach for accomplishing this task would be appreciated as well.

I am going to put in the entire code for the file because I do not know what part of it will be the relevant aspect.

In the code, it is currently set to only create a message box for each file as a test measure to ensure the variables have the values I think they have.
The commented out code for renaming the file is the truly intended purpose.
I am stuck on the proper formatting of the first part of the file however.
In general, I am executing this from the command line using: cscript.exe c:\MyTools\addDir2FileName.vbs

I launched it through windows explorer to get the more specific error codes with line numbers though.

I added the Beginning of File and End of File comments just for the purpose of clarity in this post.

```
' ####### Beginning of File
' Renames all files in a directory prepending the directory name to the file name

Imports System
Imports System.IO

Option Explicit

Dim WshShell, strOldFull, strNewFull, strFullPath, strCurDir
Dim strCurrentName, strNewName, strMessage, dir, fileObj, fs, fo

' Get the current directory
Set WshShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
strFullPath = WshShell.CurrentDirectory

'Get folder properties to get just the name without path
Set fs=Server.CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set fo=fs.GetFolder(strFullPath)

strCurDir = fo.Name

'Iterate through the directory
set dir = DirectoryInfo(strFullPath)

For Each fileObj In dir.GetFiles()
  strCurrentName = fileObj.Name
  strNewName = strCurDir & " - " & strCurrentName

  ' For testing purposes to make sure everything is as expected
  ' Creates a message box for each file instead of actually renaming it
  strMessage = "Old Name: " & strCurrentName & chr(13) & chr(10) & "New Name: " & strNewName 
  MsgBox strMessage

  ' Renaming the file
  ' strOldFull =  fs.BuildPath(CurrentDirectory, strCurrentName)
  ' strNewFull = fs.BuildPath(CurrentDirectory, strNewName)
  ' My.Computer.FileSystem.RenameFile(strOldFull, strNewFull)

Next

WshShell = Nothing
fo = Nothing
fs = Nothing

' ### End of File
```

The expectation is that a file "C:\Pictures\Trip to Nice\DCM001.jpg" will get renamed to "C:\Pictures\Trip to Nice\Trip to Nice - DCM001.jpg" and that all files in the directory that the script is run in will be similarly renamed.
Well, to be more precise, the output as currently formatted will produce a message box that says "Old Name: C:\Pictures\Trip to Nice\DCM001.jpg  New Name: C:\Pictures\Trip to Nice\Trip to Nice - DCM001.jpg" and that a message box will be produced for all files in the directory. Yes, I will only run message box version in a test directory with 3 files. I would hate to get 50,000 message boxes, lol.

There is no output at current because of the formatting issues with either the Import Statement or the Option Explicit, or perhaps some other syntax piece I am missing or have wrong.

Thank you for your time and any help that anyone is able to provide. This is the first time I am posting to the community but I have long appreciated the answers provided. Usually, I can find my questions already answered, but I am stumped on this one...

Comment: The `Imports` statements are not valid VBScript syntax.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Type mismatch: Imports in vbs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22854465/type-mismatch-imports-in-vbs)

Comment: @Geert, I don't feel this is a duplicate of that question because my question was not "What is causing this error" but rather "How do I accomplish this task" wherein I was not so much concerned about that singular aspect and was open to any given solution, as is represented in the solution I posted before you commented, which did not attempt to leverage the Imports statements.

Answer (score 1):

```
' Declare variables
Dim objFSO, objParentFolder, objFolder, objFile

' Set the parent directory to be processed
Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set objParentFolder = objFSO.GetFolder("C:\path\to\parent\directory")

' Function to process the subfolders
Sub ProcessSubFolders(folder)
    ' Loop through all files in the folder
    For Each objFile In folder.Files
        ' Get the current file name
        strFileName = objFile.Name
        ' Get the folder name
        strFolderName = folder.Name
        ' Build the new file name
        strNewFileName = strFolderName & "_" & strFileName
        ' Rename the file
        objFile.Name = strNewFileName
    Next

    ' Loop through all subfolders
    For Each objFolder In folder.SubFolders
        ' Recursively call the function for the subfolder
        ProcessSubFolders(objFolder)
    Next
End Sub

' Call the function to process the top-level folder
ProcessSubFolders(objParentFolder)

' Clean up
Set objFile = Nothing
Set objParentFolder = Nothing
Set objFSO = Nothing
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay, through a lot of trial and error, I figured out a method to complete the task where I did not use System and so avoided the error that I was receiving before.
I thought to post the final script, in case anyone was interested.

```
' Renames all files in a directory prepending the directory name to the file name
Option Explicit

Dim WshShell, strOldFull, strFullPath, strCurDir, lastSlash
Dim strCurrentName, strNewName, strMessage, fileObj, fileSpec, fs, fo, ff

' Get the current directory
Set WshShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
strFullPath = WshShell.CurrentDirectory

'Get folder object 
Set fs = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set fo = fs.GetFolder(strFullPath)
set ff = fo.Files

'Get just the folder name
lastSlash = inStrRev(strFullPath, "\")
strCurDir = right(strFullPath, len(strFullPath) - lastSlash )


'Iterate through the directory
For Each fileObj in ff
  strCurrentName = fileObj.Name
  strNewName = strCurDir & " - " & strCurrentName

  ' For testing purposes to make sure everything is as expected
  ' Creates a message box for each file instead of actually renaming it
  ' strMessage = "Old Name: " & strCurrentName & chr(13) & chr(10) & "New Name: " & strNewName 
  ' MsgBox strMessage

  ' Renaming the file
  strOldFull =  strFullPath & "\" & strCurrentName
  set fileSpec = fs.GetFile(strOldFull)
  fileSpec.Name = strNewName

Next
```